# Temporary attribute in boost spirit needed for parsing

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I have a file which format is of form "$number_of_elements $e1 $e2 $e3". I have created following parser:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/boost_tuple.hpp>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string input("2 3 3\n");

  using boost::phoenix::at_c;
  using boost::spirit::qi::_1;
  using boost::spirit::qi::_r1;
  using boost::spirit::qi::double_;
  using boost::spirit::qi::omit;
  using boost::spirit::qi::int_;
  using boost::spirit::qi::repeat;
  using boost::spirit::qi::rule;
  using boost::spirit::qi::space;
  using boost::spirit::qi::space_type;
  using boost::spirit::qi::_val;

  rule<std::string::iterator, double(), space_type> r0 = double_;
  r0.name("r0");
  rule<std::string::iterator, std::vector<double>(size_t), space_type> r1 = repeat(_r1)[r0];
  r1.name("r1");
  rule<std::string::iterator, boost::tuple<size_t, std::vector<double> >(), space_type> r2
    = int_ >> r1(at_c<0>(_val));
  r2.name("r2");
  rule<std::string::iterator, std::vector<double>(), space_type> r3
    = r2[_val = at_c<1>(_1)];
  r3.name("r3");
  debug(r0);
  debug(r1);
  debug(r2);
  debug(r3);
  std::vector<double> res;
  bool success = boost::spirit::qi::phrase_parse(input.begin(),
                                                 input.end(),
                                                 r3,
                                                 space,
                                                 res);
  if (success) {
    for(std::vector<double>::iterator it = res.begin(); it != res.end(); it++) {
      std::cout << *it << " " << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return !success;
}
```

I wonder if there is a chance of avoiding copy. I don't know boost phoenix (or gcc) to say if the temporary object removal optimization will be applied by compiler (the amount of data can be quite large so it might affect the performance).

Also - is it possible to alter the `r1` rule into something like (unless it is done so by repeat):

```
  rule<std::string::iterator, std::vector<double>(size_t), space_type> r1
    = eps[_val.reserve(_r1)] >> repeat(_r1)[r0];
```

(This line does not compile).

**PS**. The amount of stored can be quite large so while it doesn't matter at this point copying/reallocating might have some impact - however I would prefer to know what does such optimization involve before fully committing to design.

**PPS**. I'm using gcc 4.4 so I do have access to `std::move` but not many other C++11 features.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, this one took me sometime to get right, firstly I had to clean up the code so that I could read it correctly (I hope you don't mind) and the rest is done with Semantic actions:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_NO_PREDEFINED_TERMINALS

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>  
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_bind.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_stl.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    namespace qi=boost::spirit::qi;
    namespace phx=boost::phoenix;

    //we use no predefined terms to speed up compile times
    qi::double_type double_;
    qi::int_type    int_;
    qi::_1_type     _1;
    qi::_val_type   _val;

    std::string in="3 3.4 5.6 6.7";
    auto first=in.cbegin(),
         last =in.cend();

    std::vector<double> out;

    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, std::vector<double>()> r1=
        int_     
        [ 
            phx::bind(&std::vector<double>::reserve, _val, _1)
        ]
        >>    ' ' %
            double_
            [ 
                phx::push_back(_val, _1) 
            ]
        ;

    qi::parse(first, last, r1, out);

    std::copy(out.cbegin(), out.cend(),
        std::ostream_iterator<double>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Output:

```
3.4
5.6
6.7
```

Can be seen working here:

[http://liveworkspace.org/code/QBPdC$1](http://liveworkspace.org/code/QBPdC%241)

Answer (score 1):

There is [`std::swap`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/swap/) by `boost::pheonix::swap` which avoids copy.

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/boost_tuple.hpp>


namespace ph = boost::phoenix;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  std::string input("2 3 3\n");

  qi::rule<std::string::iterator, qi::space_type, double()> r0
    = qi::double_;
  r0.name("r0");
  // I'm not sure why this qi::omit is needed but without it the output is empty
  qi::rule<std::string::iterator, qi::space_type, std::vector<double>(size_t)> r1
    = qi::omit[qi::eps[ph::reserve(qi::_val, qi::_r1)]] >> qi::repeat(qi::_r1)[r0];
  r1.name("r1");
  qi::rule<std::string::iterator, qi::space_type, boost::tuple<size_t, std::vector<double> >()> r2
    = qi::int_ >> r1(ph::at_c<0>(qi::_val));
  r2.name("r2");
  qi::rule<std::string::iterator, qi::space_type, std::vector<double>()> r3
    = r2[ph::swap(qi::_val, ph::at_c<1>(qi::_1))];
  r3.name("r3");
  std::vector<double> res;
  bool success = qi::phrase_parse(input.begin(),
                  input.end(),
                  r3,
                  qi::space,
                  res);
  if (success) {
    for(std::vector<double>::iterator it = res.begin(); it != res.end(); it++) {
      std::cout << *it << " " << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return !success;
}
```

(Sorry for unclear code but I treated it as playground for `boost::spirit`)

Comment: @llonesmiz: If you post it as answer I would accepted - this question is about locals.